# I was denied entry to the UK at the airport. How do I apply for a visa to visit a friend, not immigrate?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, removal, denial-of-entry

I am an American. I thought Americans could travel to the UK without a visa. I was denied entry when I arrived at the airport.

I bought a one-way ticket because I wanted to buy a return ticket when I was ready to leave.

Now, I need a visa to enter the UK. I want to visit for 30 days.

What should I do?

Comment: >I thought Americans could travel in UK without visa - you are correct but nothing, not even a visa guarantees the immigration authorities will let you enter any country, that decision is always made at the border. Please post the refusal notice with personal details redacted so we can answer you better.

Comment: @pnuts well, during a visa process she has a better chance of proving ties to the USA but let's see the notice first.

Comment: American citizens can visit the UK without a visa for up to 6 months - however the UK border officer can always refuse entry to any non-EEA national who doesn't fulfil the criteria for admission.
Knowing the way they work, at a first glance I suspect that you failed to convince them that you were a genuine visitor (as opposed to seeking to work there and/or stay longer than 6 months, which requires a visa) - a one-way ticket, along with lack of firm ties to your home country, could certainly raise that suspicion.
Please upload your refusal letter so we can make a more informed assessment

Comment: They gave you some paperwork when you were removed, it has something like "IS151a" or "IS151b" or ISxxxx on the top. Please scan it and use paint to blacken out your name and personal details. Then you can edit your question to include the image. Use http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/80637/edit See here for an example http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79978/ive-a-visa-free-passport-to-uk-but-was-refused-to-enter-in-heathrow-applied-fo

Comment: Does the removal notice actually change the answer to this question? Then answer is presumably "Apply for a visa. If you were accused of deception, get a (UK) immigration lawyer first."

Comment: @CMaster you need to see which type of notice was served, there are about 5 or 6 types.  It could very well be to apply for an entry clearance, but entry clearance is NOT required for Americans.  Even if they have been bounced.

Comment: Realistically I guess OP is either trying to (A) get married or (B) work there. Quite simply, the only way forward is **get a solicitor**. Hire the best immigration attorney.