# I was refused entry to the UK, will I have a problem traveling to Turkey?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, turkey, tourist-visas

I posted a couple of months ago that I was refused to enter the UK in September 2016: 
[I've a visa-free passport to UK but was refused to enter in Heathrow. Applied for a visa as advised by IO but still refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79978/ive-a-visa-free-passport-to-uk-but-was-refused-to-enter-in-heathrow-applied-fo)

Now, I made plans to have my vacation in Turkey to visit a couple of friends there, for 2 weeks from 1/1/17 - 16/1/2017.

My questions:
1. Will I have a problem at Turkish immigration in regards to the UK entry refusal?
2. Do I have to explain to them the 'X' mark in my passport in regards to the UK entry refusal? Should I explain and tell the truth or offer some white lie?
3. I have a valid visa-free passport, statement of account of 6 months and email of hotel confirmation as proof for visitation. Will that be sufficient?

From my understanding, I think I should not have any problems visiting Turkey as they are not in the Schengen Area, therefore they do not share the database containing my UK entry refusal. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 8):

### Denouement (2 Jan 2017)

The OP returned to advise on the outcome. Here's his comment...

> so I'm in turkey now. There was no formalities at the airport at all.
>   The IO didn't ask anything about the X on my passport. He just looked
>   at it. Stamped my passport and winked. And I went through. Call me
>   lucky but that's how you're supposed to travel. So it doesn't matter
>   whether u have a 'X' from the UK. It does not deter u from visiting
>   other countries. So it's just the UK that are so paranoid

In short, the OP breezed past the official. A great outcome with the bottom line that a UK refusal stamp did not alarm the Turkish border official. This type of mobility has the side effect of mitigating UKVI's response in the future.  None of the OP's experience contradicts the original answer, so it's left intact.

---

### Previous Answer

You were refused entry at the UK border and then refused for UK entry clearance, so you have two indications in your passport. You want to travel to Turkey as a visa-free national and you are having anxiety about what will happen...

To begin, you will be in the official's *discretionary zone*. I.e., he has discretion that can play in your favour or against you.

> Will I have a problem at the Turkey immigration in regards to the UK
>   entry refusal?

If they see the one or two refusal indicators, they will certainly follow up with some questions.  This is the time to remember that virtually all interaction with border officials is governed by personal impact and articulation skills.  You will have to think how to respond. It is also a textbook example of where mock interviews in advance can be especially helpful.

> Should I explain the truth or insert some white lie?

Long proven experience informs us that they have experience in assessing the response to awkward questions. They are expecting you to waffle and hedge. They will watch for you to break eye contact and shift nervously etc etc. The optimal strategy is to be delightfully candid, charmingly so.  Again, personal impact will dictate how things go when a person's situation is in the discretionary zone. Your role is to help the officer do his job and you should acquit yourself of this onus in a transparent and streamlined way.

To be clear about it: If you play cat-and-mouse you will lose. If you shift blame on to your uncle or whatever you will lose. If you say that British IO's are stupid you will lose.  Remember that lots of Turkish border officials are initially trained in the UK (also in Prague) and continue to take advanced courses in the UK and they *totally know* what provokes a UK removal.

> I have a valid visa-free passport, statement of account of 6 months
>   and email of hotel confirmation as proof for visitation. Will that be
>   sufficient?

No, it's not sufficient. You should bring in hand luggage all of the items you used to apply for entry clearance, not just bank statements and hotel confirms. Stuff like employment contract, who your friends are etc etc.  Your stuff should be well organised and easily accessible.  Once again, mock interviews can be helpful.

> therefore they do not share the database containing my UK entry
>   refusal.

This type of concern is relevant only for people with something to hide. It's against our site ethos to be supportive for those wanting to hide something. Hopefully that means it's irrelevant for you also.

> Geographically Turkey falls under Asia (just a small part under
>   Europe) shouldn't it be easier?

No. Turkey is an accession candidate for the EU. It means their national aspirations and national identity is allied with Europe's. *Allegedly*. Politically your mileage may vary, but at the border diligent people will treat the occasion  as entering a European country.

---

Side note: you wrote: "*...as advised by the IO...*". Generally ignore what IO's advise you. During a removal situation their job is to get you out of the UK with a minimum of fuss and bother. They will tell you *anything*. They will promise the sun, moon, and stars if it keeps you quiet and orderly.  Yes, you should apply for entry clearance, but they made it sound like a mechanical formality and you would have no problems. I know that line quite well, it gets you satisfied that everything will turn out OK.  It's *not* a mechanical formality. Honestly, in a removal situation, just ignore their 'advice'.

Comment: Gayot, if u mentioned that I should bring in hand luggage all of the items that I used to apply for entry clearance and also the paperwork for initial refusal at Heathrow, don't u think i will be in a disadvantage position? the refusal letter indicated that "intention to produce fraudulent documentation" would definitely not bring a good rapport to me. There is no way I can come out with an excuse for that unless u have a suggestion. Will I be scrutinise forever for every country I visit even Asia? Geographically Turkey falls under Asia (just a small part under Europe) shouldn't it be easier?

Comment: I mean you should bring exhibits from here https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf  For your other question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: so I'm in turkey now. There was no formalities at the airport at all. The IO didn't ask anything about the X on my passport. He just looked at it. Stamped my passport and winked. And I went through. Call me lucky but that's how you're supposed to travel. So it doesn't matter whether u have a 'X' from the UK. It does not deter u from visiting other countries. So it's just the UK that are so paranoid